# SDL2 program only works if Renderer is created with SDL_RENDERER_SOFTWARE

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2

I've written a program using C++ and SDL2 which:

1. creates a window
2. gets the window's surface
3. creates a renderer for the window
4. renders some filled rectangles onto the window
5. creates a texture from the window's surface
6. clears the screen
7. renders some filled circles onto the window
8. creates a second texture from the window's surface
9. enters an event loop, where every time a key is pressed:
10. if circles are currently being displayed, SDL_RenderCopy() is used to copy the squares texture to the window.
11. else if squares are currently being displayed, the circles texture is copied to the window.

The program works perfectly if the renderer is created with the `SDL_RENDERER_SOFTWARE` flag.

If the renderer is created with the `SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED` flag, I find that while I can render direct to the screen, if I create a couple of different textures from the window's surface and then try to copy them back to the window using `SDL_RenderCopy()`; all I see is a black window.

I can't find any failing SDL calls.

I've wondered whether there might be some incompatibility between the texture format and the renderer - but I'm not sure how to follow this up.

Any help or suggestions?

My environment is :

- Windows 10
- Visual Studio Community 2015
- SDL2 version 2.0.4

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Additional information and source code :

I've added cut down source code to demonstrate the problem below.

Note, to keep down the size, I've removed all of the error checking and consolidated the relevant code into a single main function.

What I get is that the program works for me as expected if I uncomment line 40 so that I am calling `SDL_CreateRenderer` with the `SDL_RENDERER_SOFTWARE` flag.

If I un-comment any of the other `SDL_CreateRenderer` lines instead (line 41-43 : to use hardware acceleration), I see the red and blue squares when they are initially rendered to screen.

But as I press keys, instead of the window flicking between red and blue squares, I'm looking at a black window.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_image.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>


//Screen dimension constants
const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 640;
const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 480;


int main(int argc, char* args[])
{

    //The window we'll be rendering to
    SDL_Window* gWindow = NULL;

    //The surface contained by the window
    SDL_Surface* gScreenSurface = NULL;

    //And two textures, one for a red square, on for a blue square
    SDL_Texture* texture_red = NULL;
    SDL_Texture* texture_blue = NULL;

    //The window renderer
    SDL_Renderer* gRenderer = NULL;


    //Initialize SDL
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);

    //Create window
    gWindow = SDL_CreateWindow("SDL Tutorial", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);

    //Get the screen surface
    gScreenSurface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(gWindow);


    //Create renderer for window
    gRenderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(gWindow, -1, SDL_RENDERER_SOFTWARE);
    //gRenderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(gWindow, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
    //gRenderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(gWindow, -1, SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC);
    //gRenderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(gWindow, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_TARGETTEXTURE);

    /*###########################################################################################
    # I can not figure out how to make this program work with hardware acceleration. It works   #
    # fine when I define the renderer using SDL_RENDERER_SOFTWARE, but doesn't display anything #
    # if I define the renerer using the SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED flag                           #
    ###########################################################################################*/

    //Initialize renderer color
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(gRenderer, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF);


    //Clear screen
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(gRenderer, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF);
    SDL_RenderClear(gRenderer);

    //Render red filled quad
    SDL_Rect fillRect = { 100, 75, 100, 100 };
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(gRenderer, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF);
    SDL_RenderFillRect(gRenderer, &fillRect);

    //Update the rendered image on screen
    SDL_RenderPresent(gRenderer);

    //Pause long enough to see it
    SDL_Delay(200);

    //Create texture_red texture from the screen surface
    texture_red = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(gRenderer, gScreenSurface);


    //Clear screen
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(gRenderer, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF);
    SDL_RenderClear(gRenderer);

    //Render blue filled quad
    fillRect = { 225, 250, 100, 100 };
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(gRenderer, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF);
    SDL_RenderFillRect(gRenderer, &fillRect);

    //Update the rendered image on screen
    SDL_RenderPresent(gRenderer);

    //Pause long enough to see it
    SDL_Delay(200);

    //Create texture_red texture from the screen surface
    texture_blue = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(gRenderer, gScreenSurface);


    //Main loop flag
    bool quit = false;

    //Flag to keep track of which colour we're currently looking at
    bool blue = true;

    //Event handler
    SDL_Event e;

    //While application is running
    while (!quit)
    {
        //Handle events on queue
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&e) != 0)
        {
            //User requests quit
            if (e.type == SDL_QUIT)
            {
                quit = true;
            }
            //User presses a key
            else if (e.type == SDL_KEYDOWN)
            {
                //Select surfaces based on key press
                switch (e.key.keysym.sym)
                {

                case SDLK_ESCAPE:
                    quit = true;
                    break;

                default:
                    if (blue)
                    {
                        //Copy surface used to store red image onto the screen surface
                        SDL_RenderCopy(gRenderer, texture_red, NULL, NULL);

                        //Update current colour flag
                        blue = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        //Copy surface used to store blue image onto the screen surface
                        SDL_RenderCopy(gRenderer, texture_blue, NULL, NULL);

                        //Update current colour flag
                        blue = true;
                    }

                    //Update the screen with recent render activity
                    SDL_RenderPresent(gRenderer);

                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }


    //Deallocate surfaces
    SDL_FreeSurface(gScreenSurface);

    //Destroy window
    SDL_DestroyWindow(gWindow);
    gWindow = NULL;

    //Quit SDL subsystems
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `SDL_GetWindowSurface` documentation says "You may not combine this with 3D or the rendering API on this window.". Create render texture (`SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_TARGET`), set it as render target and then draw whatever you wanted.

Answer (score 6):

The `SDL_GetWindowSurface()` [header comment](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/blob/a21e6af514bc98bcfdc812a28cd04aed992c1274/include/SDL_video.h#L761-L774) specifically prohibits using it with the SDL_Renderer functionality:

```
/**
 *  \brief Get the SDL surface associated with the window.
 *
 *  \return The window's framebuffer surface, or NULL on error.
 *
 *  A new surface will be created with the optimal format for the window,
 *  if necessary. This surface will be freed when the window is destroyed.
 *
 *  \note You may not combine this with 3D or the rendering API on this window.
 *
 *  \sa SDL_UpdateWindowSurface()
 *  \sa SDL_UpdateWindowSurfaceRects()
 */
extern DECLSPEC SDL_Surface * SDLCALL SDL_GetWindowSurface(SDL_Window * window);
```

Use `SDL_RENDERER_TARGETTEXTURE` & [`SDL_SetRenderTarget()`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_SetRenderTarget) if you want to capture SDL_Renderer output.

You can use [`SDL_GetRendererInfo()`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetRendererInfo) to query a compatible texture format.  Or just blast ahead with `SDL_PIXELFORMAT_ARGB8888` [like `testrendertarget.c` does](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/blob/a21e6af514bc98bcfdc812a28cd04aed992c1274/test/testrendertarget.c#L109) and hope for the best :)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC` to your renderer's flag (Proposed by someone [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49388918/sdl2-strange-behaviour-of-hardware-rendering/49400962#49400962)).

C++ seems to be the programming language you're using but for those looking for a fully working SDL2.0.8-based C program that does not use `GetWindowSurface()`, please take a look [here](https://github.com/BoubacarDiene/mmstreamer/blob/master/src/graphics/drawers/Drawer2.c):

Mainly,

- initWindowAndRenderer
- drawText
- drawImage
- drawVideo
- setBgColor
- drawVideo
- ...

Here is an extract with error-checking removed:

```
// Create a window usable with OpenGL context
window = SDL_CreateWindow("Title", x, y, w, h, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL|SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);

// Select render driver
// - A render driver that supports HW acceleration is used when available
// - Otherwise a render driver supporting software fallback is selected
SDL_RendererInfo renderDriverInfo;
uint32_t rendererFlags  = SDL_RENDERER_TARGETTEXTURE;
int32_t nbRenderDrivers = SDL_GetNumRenderDrivers(), index = 0;

while (index < nbRenderDrivers)
{
    if (SDL_GetRenderDriverInfo(index, &renderDriverInfo) == 0)
    {
        if (((renderDriverInfo.flags & rendererFlags) == rendererFlags)
            && ((renderDriverInfo.flags & SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED) == SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED))
        {
            // Using render driver with HW acceleration
            rendererFlags |= SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED;
            SDL_SetHint(SDL_HINT_RENDER_DRIVER, renderDriverInfo.name);
            break;
        }
    }
    ++index;
}

if (index == nbRenderDrivers)
{
    // Let SDL use the first render driver supporting software fallback
    rendererFlags |= SDL_RENDERER_SOFTWARE;
    index = -1;
}

// Create renderer
renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, index, rendererFlags);
```